# Can lack of dual citizenship be a job qualification in Canada?

Tags: canada, citizenship, employment, dual-citizenship

Some organizations in Canada have an official preference for hiring Canadian citizens, and say so in job announcements. If one is a Canadian citizen but also a U.S. citizen, does that mean one would be treated differently from a candidate who is only a Canadian citizen?

Comment: Does it ask if you are a Canadian citizen _only_? If not, why would you share? No one’s business unless it’s a national security sort of thing, but even there: I guess they would ask, right?

Comment: @kisspuska : I applied for a job in Toronto where I was asked whether I am a Canadian citizen and whether I am a U.S. citizen and I answered "yes" to both.

Comment: Oh, ok! I thought the medium was like a form or something. Did they deny the job app on that basis?

Comment: (My gut feeling is if they announce it, I would have a bad feeling that some statutes would support that. Just common sense: I don’t think they would dare to engage in a blatant discrimination if the legislation wouldn’t support them, but hopefully someone will know the answer for sure.)

Comment: It was "a form or something", i.e. a web page where you click on things.

Comment: "official preference for hiring Canadian citizens" What kind of organization? That in itself is illegal in Ontario if without particular reasons.

Comment: @xngtng : A postsecondary institution.

Comment: Many Canadian companies do much of their business with the U.S. - I believe it is still Canada's largest trading partner. Having an employee with dual citizenship who is therefore able to travel freely to either country is actually an advantage in some cases. I have worked for several such companies. The immediately obvious disadvantage is how and where the employee is paid and taxed, and if the Canadian firm has a significant U.S. presence they are set up to deal with that.

Answer (score 5):

### It is illegal to discriminate on the basis of "national or ethnic origin"

This is spelled out in the [Canadian Human Rights Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/h-6/fulltext.html) s3(1).

However, a person's citizenship is something that can (must) be discriminated on. **Unless** it is being used as a proxy for "national or ethnic origin".

### Right to work in Canada

To be allowed to work in Canada, person must be a:

1. Canadian citizen (including dual-nationals),
2. non-Canadian citizen and hold a [work-permit](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/eligibility.html),
3. non-Canadian citizen and be doing [exempt](https://www.settler.ca/english/work-in-canada-without-a-permit-legally/) work.

So, an employer asking about citizenship to determine eligibility is fine. An employer asking to discriminate in favour of group 1 over group 2 or 3 is not.

Comment: CHRA doesn't apply to most employees in Canada whose employers are not under federal jurisdiction. Citizenship is a protected ground in Ontario and several other provinces.

Comment: When I posted the question I did not yet suspect that the rules apply differently to universities.

Answer (score 2):

Employment and human rights law are mostly provincial if the employer/service provider is not federally regulated.

[Federally regulated sectors](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/jobs/workplace/federally-regulated-industries.html) are out of provincial jurisdiction with respect to employment and are subject to the federal Acts (Canadian Human Rights Act, Canada Labour Code) instead.

[Citizenship](http://www.ohrc.on.ca/en/part-ii-%E2%80%93-interpretation-and-application/canadian-citizenship) is a enumerated protected ground in Ontario. Employment decisions cannot be discriminate on citizenship (e.g. requirement to have Canadian citizenship) unless a legal requirement exists. Certain general exceptions apply, e.g. essential job duty or business requirement, certain social/cultural/religious organizations.

> Some organizations in Canada have an official preference for hiring Canadian citizens

This in itself could be illegal (if they are subject to Ontario law).

> If one is a Canadian citizen but also a U.S. citizen, does that mean one would be treated differently from a candidate who is only a Canadian citizen?

This would also be illegal.

If the job requires security clearance or work eligibility in the US, dual citizenship can be taken into account at that stage (for better or worse).

Citizenship is also often closely related to national origin or ancestry which is a protected ground in all provinces and federally. Even if your particular citizenship has no relations with your national origin, it might still be an illegal discrimination.

Comment: Here's an example: "The University of Manitoba is strongly committed to equity and diversity within its community and especially welcomes applications from women, racialized persons, Indigenous peoples, persons with disabilities, persons of all sexual and gender identities, and others who may contribute to the further diversification of ideas. All qualified candidates are encouraged to apply; however, Canadian citizens and permanent residents will be given priority."

Comment: The URL for an announcement from which I quote above was actually too long to post as a comment, by 57 characters. It appears that the University of Manitoba uses Google to host its job announcements rather than putting them on the university's own web site.

Comment: Here's one: https://library.queensu.ca/sites/default/files/admin/head_open_scholarship_services_job_posting_0_0.pdf This one says "All qualified candidates are encouraged to apply; however, Canadian citizens and permanent residents will be given priority."

Comment: And: "To comply with Federal laws, the University is obliged to gather statistical information about how many applicants for each job vacancy are Canadian citizens/ permanent residents of Canada. Applicants need not identify their country of origin or citizenship, however, all applications must include one of the following statements: I am a Canadian citizen/permanent resident of Canada; OR, I am not a Canadian citizen/permanent resident of Canada. Applications that do not include this information will be deemed incomplete."

Comment: @MichaelHardy is there any category of non-citizen other than permanent resident that comes with work authorization requiring no sponsorship or other paperwork from the employer?  If not, then I would interpret this question as being equivalent to "are you independently authorized to work in Canada?"  On the other hand, I can't imagine why they're asking whether you're a US citizen.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Aha, post-secondary institutions have a federal policy requirement to give preference to Canadian citizens and because they are given an exemption to do simultaneous recruitment. It is considered to be ["authorized by law"](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onhrt/doc/2013/2013hrto691/2013hrto691.html) (a constitutional argument could be raised in a court but no one that has standing has tried AFAIK). Double citizenship discrimination doesn't appear to be "authorized" though.

Comment: @xngtng : Might that raise a question about the legality of their asking that question?

Comment: @phoog Open work permits do exist but they are limited in time. The Human Rights Tribunal decided that it could be illegal discrimination to require an applicant to be able to work in Canada indefinitely, but that decision was overturned very recently in [Court](https://www.canlii.org/en/on/onscdc/doc/2021/2021onsc3868/2021onsc3868.html) (though I find the majority reasoning to be unreasonable; but HRTO's decision was not written well neither...; I don't know if an appeal has been/will be filed). Disqualifying permanent residents without statutory basis is almost always illegal though.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It depends on why they ask, like for other possible discrimination claims. If they have good reasons, it might not be straightup illegal. Asking if you are Canadian citizen usually would be problematic; asking if you are Canadian citizen or permanent resident, less so; asking if you are citizens of a foreign state would be problematic but there could be other justifications.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  If I could make a wild guess: perhaps they want to know if they can hire you under NAFTA (but that should include Mexican citizens too), perhaps they need to deal with US sanctioned countries (Cuba, Iran...), or perhaps they are interested in funding that only US citizens may apply. But still, the question is sufficiently unusual to me.